# Closing questions is affected by other aspects

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions, closed-questions

I've always found it difficult to post questions here as opposed to other websites.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462562/euclidean-travelling-salesman-instance-using-mst-heuristics) and tell me why it is unclear? I've clearly stated my question and edited it when a user said that it was not clear. It then got closed.

I have thought about the question for an entire week before posting it here. I am here to seek knowledge and it is always difficult to get my questions answered.

Moreover, all the users who voted to close my question seem not to be expert in that area. Is it my low reputation that makes people eager about closing the question or is it something that I don't clearly see?

Maybe it is a language barrier because I am not a native speaker.

Comment: You should explain in your question what you've been hiding beyond links and references. It's unclear as can be. That doesn't have anything to do with your english capabilities.

Comment: Your question should stand alone without the link

Comment: Upvoted you because you've come here to Meta to *learn how to ask a better question* and have politely asked without ranting or moaning, and we want to encourage all this, don't we, downvoters...? Although, do have a search and read, as there are lot's of good questions already about asking a good question :)

Answer (score 15):

It is not your reputation. That has nothing to do with it. Your question is simply not all that good.

First of all, I don't think that the question is really on-topic for Stack Overflow which deals with programming questions (the type-on-the-keyboard kind). Yours seems to be more theoretical CS oriented. But I hesitate to suggest a specific site to move the question to.

Secondly, your question is not self-contained. Understanding the question seems to rely mostly on an external resource you expect us to check out and read. That is a problem. You should revise your question so that it can be understood in full by just looking at the question itself. You can still link to the external resource, but it should not be necessary.

With that done, perhaps provide a bit more information as well on how you failed to achieve what you want to achieve, if that may help to clarify the question or to point out where you went wrong.

I'd say those are the main issues that lead to closure.

Answer (score 13):

*"Explain to me this particular section of this blog / lecture / book"* is not the sort of question that will be well-received here.

First and foremost, it is unclear what exactly you failed to understand. The 134 page lecture you linked is after all specifically intended to teach you this material. If it failed to do so, then how can a short one-page answer here achieve the same, if you don't even tell at which step you failed.

Second, most people will be unwilling to load a 134 page pdf, find the section you specified, read all previous sections required to understand the terminology etc., just to be able to fuly grasp the scope of your question, let alone answer it.

So, in order to make his question into a better question, I would advice that you:

- state the problem in your own words. Anyone familiar with the general concepts, but unfamiliar with that particluar lecture, should be able to understand your question.
- state what exactly you want to achieve, what you have tried and where you failed. Saying that you "failed all the way" tells the reader nothing useful about your attempts.
- while reformulating the question in this way, make sure that it is actually ontopic here, and not better suited e.g. to cs.stackexchange.com.

You may find that while putting all this effort into the question, the quesion answers itself. That is a good thing, it means [stackoverflow's magic debugging powers are working](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).

Comment: SO rubber duck debugger is best debugger!